# Calculate Total fun from 4 cities . Interview Question DSA round

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Given there are cities , and each city has a fun factor associated with it . There is a bidirectional path between cities . Calculate the max total fun by choosing only 4 cities and show the list of cities .

```
Eg :
Fun factors
LA- 10000
CH- 1000
Del- 5
Iowa- 200
Mum-50000

Paths-
LA - CH
Ch-Iowa
Del-Iowa
Del-mum
```

O\p - mum,del,iowa,ch : 51205

Comment: Choose the four cities with the greatest fun.  As you state the problem, the paths between cities are irrelevant.  You must have left something out.

Comment: I think you're just looking for all paths with no more than 3 edges (although as ravenspoint commented, the problem statement needs some work). These can be found with a depth-limited DFS starting at each city.

Comment: I _think_ the aim is to find a unique path consisting of `4` distinct cities so that the total fun factor is the highest.